# Multi Store , change site/theme according to domain name

Tags: php, laravel

i want to make multi-store system with Laravel. There will be one website but different stores. 
I want to switch themes and contents according to domain name.

For example i have 2 sites or more :

```
127.0.0.1 www.firststore.com
127.0.0.1 www.secondstore.com
```

System should check domain name and according to domain name it should fetch its own config from db. With this config it should switch theme and content of site.

How can i develop this system ?

Many thanks for any opinion!

Comment: assuming you are using apache, you can use .htaccess to bootstrap different applications

Comment: You can trigger a switch using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` in PHP

Comment: is it possible to fetch domain name and change the theme according to domain name

Comment: How can i use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?`

Answer (score 1):

The best way should be a middleware and for example the view()->share() method to bring your css into the view.

In the middleware you can do something like Request::getHost() and than retrieve a Store model by this host from your database after this you can set variables, for the following process. And you can add scopes to your models that are store related like scopeHost($query, $host) to select just the models that are related to your current Store.

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes